# Java Command-Line Calculator Help. Adding a Sequences of Numbers

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement, calculator

so I'm building a simple calculator for class. I have most of it down but I'm having trouble as it's stated that the calculator after + needs to sum a sequence of numbers. I know I need to do something with the array but I'm not completely sure what. Any help or advice would be appreciated, thank you!

Output example:

```
java hw1.Calculator + 3 2 5.2 2 

sum: 12.2
```

My code so far:

```
public class Calculator3 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
       
    if (args.length != 3) {
      System.out.println("Usage: java  Calculator3  double  op  double\n" +
                         "where op can be +, -, x, or /");
      System.exit(-1);                      
    }
    double d1 = 0.0, d2 = 0.0;
    try {
      d1 = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
      d2 = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      // System.out.println(e);
      System.out.println("Error: at least one of the operands is not a number");
      System.exit(-2);
    }
    /*
    finally    {
     System.out.println("Finally clause executed. ");
    }
    */
    char op = args[1].charAt(0);
    double result = 0;
    switch (op) {
      default:
        System.out.println("Error: accepted operators are +, -, x, and /");
        System.exit(-3);
      case '+': 
        result = d1 + d2;
        break;
      case '-':
        result = d1 - d2;
        break;
      case 'x':
      case 'X':
        result = d1 * d2;
        break;
      case '/':
        result = d1 / d2;
        break;
     
        
    }
    System.out.println(d1 + " " + op + " " + d2 + " = " + result);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code do something quite different: it solve basic opeation with two operand like "a+b=c", you are asking to do something else. Stackoverflow is not a place to ask for solution of your homework, unless you "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first', as stated in metastack rules https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is only for 2 numbers.
I suppose your program has to serve for several numbers as you say, that you have to do something with arrays.

You have an array:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

- take the first argument as operation and all following as numbers.
- then use System.arraycopy(...) to separate the operands
- then you could transform the operand arrays (until now are strings) to numbers.
- then you could use java8 streams in order to sum it up. Alternatively you use a loop. (https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/)

I hope it helps but I don't wanted to comple you homework.